# Ruby 2.7 and TLS 1.3 with RestClient not working

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, rest-client, tls1.3

I'm having problems trying to request an endpoint that is using TLS 1.3

```rb
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'
require 'rest-client'

auth_payload = {
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  scope: 'cobrancas.boletos-info cobrancas.boletos-requisicao'
}

encoded_token = Base64.strict_encode64(
  'MY_CLIENT_ID:MY_CLIENT_SECRET'
)

response = RestClient::Request.execute(
  method: 'post',
  url: "https://oauth.sandbox.bb.com.br/oauth/token",
  payload: auth_payload,
  verify_ssl: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
  headers: {
    content_type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    authorization: "Basic #{encoded_token}"
  }
)
```

I tried removing `verify_ssl` and adding `ssl_version: 'TLSv1_3'` and it returned the error `unknown SSL method TLSv1_3 (ArgumentError)`

Passing the `verify_ssl: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` attribute sometimes works and sometimes returns the error `Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (Errno::ECONNRESET)`

Without passing the `verify_ssl` and `ssl_version` attributes returns the error `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=1.1.1.1:443 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate) (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`

Tried using Ruby 2.7.6 and 3.1.2 both don't work.

Through CURL it worked every time I tried (and there were many)

```sh
curl -X POST https://oauth.sandbox.bb.com.br/oauth/token -v \
     -H "Authorization: Basic ${MY_TOKEN}" \
     -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

I did a lot of research on the internet, as I understand it, Ruby still doesn't support https endpoints that use TLS 1.3, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

`OPEN_SSL` has deprecated `ssl_version` parameter, try using `min_version` as mentioned [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLContext.html#method-i-ssl_version-3D).

I see that you are using `RestClient` it is possible that the gem is not updated to use the new format for OpenSSL.

you can use the code below to test the console's SSL version.

```rb
hostname = "google.com"
ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new()
s = TCPSocket.new(hostname, 443)
ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(s, ctx)
ssl.hostname = hostname
ssl.connect
p ssl.ssl_version # "TLSv1.3"
```